# How do I go to the git repo of an IntelliJ IDEA project in the git terminal?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Git in the terminal looks for .git in the home folder. How do I move it to the git repository of an IntelliJ IDEA project? I need to add a remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found it out.

Just use

```
cd /path/to/intellijideaproject
```

and then use the git command you wish to use.

In my case:

```
cd /Users/Jop/IdeaProjects/Bind
git remote add Bind https://github.com/Jop-V/Bind.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable

```
set GIT_DIR=/path/to/your/repo/.git
```

Then any git command would be considering:

- the current folder as a working tree
- the git repo as the one in `/path/to/your/repo/.git`

Comment: Where is the .git located for IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @Jop If the IDEA project is under version, the `.git` would be right beneath the top directory of that project.

Comment: @Jop could you launch a global search for any `.git` directory on your disk, then, to track it down?